# .NET MVC5 Sessions not ending

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am fairly new to .NET and am having the following issue. I am working on an internal application that uses Window Authentication.
I need to create a temporary object and store it in the database for the duration of the session. Once the session ends, I no longer need that object.

I have code in Session_start that creates the object, and code in Session_end that destroys it.

```
    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ();
        MyObject o = new MyObject () { Temporary = 1 };
        db.MyObjects.Add(o);
        db.SaveChanges();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("my_object_id", o.ID);
    }

    protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ();
        try
        {
            MyObject o = db.MyObjects.Find(HttpContext.Current.Session["my_object_id"]);
            db.MyObjects.Remove(o);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

I also have the following xml entry in my config file

```
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
```

My issue is that these objects are being created but never destroyed. Currently we are hosting our application on a dev server, as well as running it locally with Visual Studios internal iisexpress server.

I will be trying to add some sort of logging to see if session_end is ever being called. This application will not have any sort of logout mechanism(Internal app with windows authentication).

I am not sure if I am even doing this right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the application pool lifetime?

Comment: I honestly dont know. Is there a way to check?

Comment: http://bradkingsley.com/iis7-application-pool-idle-time-out-settings/, if it's less than the session timeout you will probably not get the session end event.

Comment: Thanks, it was set to 20 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the application pool timeout is larger than the session timeout. Otherwise the application pool will be recycled before the `Session_End` method is invoked (if your site do not have many visitors).

You can find the setting here:

http://bradkingsley.com/iis7-application-pool-idle-time-out-settings/